# Post request with Spring JPA when I wish to execute an Insert query

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I wish to execute the following Insert query

```
INSERT into table_PO(
    (SELECT * from tble_PO_copy WHERE PO_id = 
        (SELECT PO_id FROM TABLE sales WHERE id =?1))
)
```

Please note that here, I do not have an entity to be inserted into the table table_PO. I have an integer that I wish to bring to the repository class.
What I used to do otherwise when I had an entity to be inserted was:

Model class

```
public Sales createSales(Sales sales) {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        Sales response = client.target(URI.contextPathUI + "/api/sales").request()
                .post(Entity.entity(sales, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Sales.class);
        return response;
}
```

Controller class

```
@Autowired
private SalesRepository salesRepository;

// ..........
// ..........

@PostMapping("/salesOrder")
    private ResponseEntity<Sales> createAdvanceSales(@RequestBody Sales sales) {
        sales = salesService.createSalesOrder(sales);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(sales, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

and in the SalesServiceImpl class

```
@Override
public Sales createSalesOrder(Sales sales) {
        sales = salesRepository.save(sales);    
}
```

But I wish to be able to implement an INSERT query. I know that I can make a repository interface that extends JpaRepository but what is the format to write the `Model class`.
Apologies for not being able to express my question as effectively as it could be. I am new to Spring and JPA.
What I really want is to write a Client-response model class so that I need not pass the entity as I used to be as shown above. I wish to mark it a post request and only pass an Integer unlike `.post(Entity.entity(sales, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Sales.class);` when I pass an entity.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider one of two options.

1. While the query doesn't use a model class it might strongly relate to a model class if this is the case I'd add a method to the repository for that model and use a `@Modifying` and a `@Query` annotation to configure the insert statement.
2. If it is really independent of any models you could just create a Spring bean, inject either a `JdbcTemplate` or an `EntityManager` into it and use it to execute the statement. So no repository in this case.